# How to insert a control between another using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to insert a control below the textbox where the cursor is located:

I have this code in MVVM, the textbox is created dynamically:

```
<ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListControls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding RGN_INdex}" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource blankColor}" Text="{Binding RGN}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2"  Content="RSN:" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource blankColor}" Text="{Binding RSN}" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="4"  Content="SGN:" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource blankColor}" Text="{Binding SGN}" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="6"  Content="SN:" Margin="5,5,0,5" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource blankColor}" Text="{Binding SN}" Grid.Column="7" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For example, I have two textboxes:

```
Textbox1 
Textbox2
```

When I put the cursor in the `Textbox1` and press a button, this will add an item in the list. Then, the view will be populated with another textbox.

So in my view, I will have this:

```
Textbox1 
Textbox3
Textbox2
```

In my XAML, I have `RGN_INdex` - this will hold the index of the control created.

In my mind I need to get the `RGN_INdex` when the cursor is focused in the control. But how can I do that? Then pass it to the command to insert in the list after where the `RGN_INdex` is found? But how can I get the `RGN_INdex` of the selected Textbox?

I'm new to MVVM and I can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: All you need to worry is insert the 3rd item in between into the `ListControls` in the `ViewModel`.

Comment: yes thats what im thinking. so i need to get the RGN_Index in order to know where should i add item in the list of my viewmodel

Comment: You can use the default collectionview of the bound observablecollection to get the indexof a specific entry https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx. You can then insertat the index of the lower one.  You need a reference to either the viewmodel of the row above or below. Use a control in the datacontext of the lower one rather than inbetween the two rows.

Comment: Can I clarify one thing, when you say "cursor is focused" is that MouseOver(where nothing is clicked) or MouseClicked(similar to item selected)?

Comment: Just a side note: please always provide a *minimal* example (see [mcve]). E.g., `FontSize` and `Margin` in your XAML are actually not needed to show your problem, they just bloat the example making it harder to read.

Comment: Where is the button that binds to the command located?

Comment: what i mean in cursor is focused is the cursor is set in the textbox. so it will retrieve the index of that control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no short answer, but let me guide you how you can do this.

Let me add the missing codes to begin with:

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
public class Ctrl
{
    public int RGN_Index { get; set; }
    public string RGN { get; set; }
    public string RSN { get; set; }
    public string SGN { get; set; }
    public string SN { get; set; }
}

public class TheViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Ctrl> ListControls { get { return _listControls; } set { SetProperty(ref _listControls, value); } }
    private ObservableCollection<Ctrl> _listControls;

    // Constructor
    public class TheViewModel()
    {
        ListControls = new ObservableCollection<Ctrl>()
        {
            new Ctrl() {RGN_Index=1,RGN="RGN1", RSN="RSN1",SGN="SGN1",SN="SN1" },
            new Ctrl() {RGN_Index=2,RGN="RGN2", RSN="RSN2",SGN="SGN2",SN="SN2" }
        };
    }

}
```

First, you need a property/ field to store the currently focused `TextBox`'s `RGN_Index` in the VM:

```
private int SelectedIndex {get; set;} = -1; // only accessed internally, so private is good enough
```

Second, you need to update this selected index when you get the cursor focus. Let's define the ICommand in your VM:

```
// Here I am binding using Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand
public ICommand GotFocusCommand {get; private set;} = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<int?>(GotFocus_Execute);
private void GotFocus_Execute(int? index)
{
   if(index != null)
      SelectedIndex = index.Value;
}
```

Then, we need to bind the `TextBox`'s `GotFocus` Event and pass the `RGN_Index` as parameter. In your xaml:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<TextBox Text="{Binding RGN}" Grid.Column="1">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.GotFocusCommand, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RGN_Index}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

You can notice that the binding requires `RelativeSource` to the `ItemsControl`'s `DataContext`. The reason is that `DataTemplate`'s `DataContext` is limited to `ListControl` and the `Command` is NOT defined in the `ListControl`, but in the VM. You can make the command static instead, but I am going to skip this.

Fourth, you must have the button to insert. So, let's define the command first in the VM:

```
public ICommand InsertCommand { get; private set; } = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand(InsertCommand_Execute);
private void InsertCommand_Execute()
{
   if (SelectedIndex > 0)
   {
      // Insert at the selected index. Note that the Ctrl inserted is just for example
      ListControls.Insert(SelectedIndex,
         new Ctrl()
         {
            RGN_Index = ++last_index, // or whatever
            RGN = $"RGN{last_index}", // or whatever
            RSN = $"RSN{last_index}", // or whatever
            SGN = $"SGN{last_index}", // or whatever
            SN = $"SN{last_index}" // or whatever
         });
   }
}
private int last_index = 2; // this is just example. You might not even need this.
```

Then bind this command to the button on your xaml:

```
<Button Content="Insert" Command="{Binding Path=InsertCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Done!

Things to consider:

1. When you click the button, your cursor is definitely not focused on the textbox anymore. Is this OK?
2. Related to the 1st one, the last focused selected index is always recorded, so in case if you click whatever other than the textbox, and then click the insert button, it is still going to work. Is this OK?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I used your idea. And it worked